# PHP error, cant insert image into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

Im new at php, I try to insert data into me database unfortunately I successfully insert name and price, but I got stuck at inserting picture (LONGBLOB), here is me code

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "tbl_product";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $image = $_FILES['image'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_product (name, image, price)
            VALUES (:name, :image, :price)');   
        $statement->execute([
                ':name' => $name,
                ':image' => $image,
                ':price' => $price,
        ]);
    }
?>
```

---

```
<div class="settings-row">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <form action="insertscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">           

            <h3>Image</h3>
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="image">

            <h3>Price</h3>
            <input type="number" class="form-control small-input" name="price" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="update" id="update">
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

```html
<? echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'" class="img-responsive"/>';?><br />
```

Comment: change $_FILES['image'] into $_FILES['image']['name']

Comment: I guess that you probably want to add the base64 encoded image data judging by the use of `longblob` so use `file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] )`??

Comment: are you sure you want to store images inside the db? Why don't you simply store the path?

Comment: I don't wont to store path, i know its not good to store image into database.

Comment: I have made a admin panel since I’m a web designer and Microsoft administrator, but In my knowledge storing image into DB is bad habit, in my case this turn out to be good, so I can later overwrite the existing images if I won’t too and more. Add, Delete, Edit data so I don’t have much maintenance on me website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment I made it appears that you wish to store the actual file data rather than the file path so use `file_get_contents` on the uploaded image - like this perhaps...

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "tbl_product";

    $conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password );
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


    /*
        catch errors
    */
    try{
        /*
            test that imprtant variables are set 
        */
        if( isset( $_POST['update'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['price'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];

            /*
                get reference to uploaded image
            */
            $obj=(object)$_FILES['image'];
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $error=$obj->error;

            /*
                if there were no errors with upload, proceed to insert into db
            */
            if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){

                /*
                    as the column is a longblob it suggests that you wish to store the actual file rather than the path
                    - this will lead to a mahoosive database in quite a short time!!
                */
                $image=base64_encode( file_get_contents( $tmp ) );


                $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_product (`name`, `image`, `price`) VALUES (:name, :image, :price)');
                $args=array(
                    ':name'     => $name,
                    ':image'    => $image,
                    ':price'    => $price
                );

                $result = $statement->execute( $args );

            } else {
                throw new Exception('Upload failed');
            }
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( $e->getMessage() );
    }
?>
```

To display an image that has been saved as base64 encoded data as above the syntax for the `img` tag needs to be modified. For example:

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPU...... etc etc
```

Comment: This code works and i can see that image is uploaded into database but i dont get any result displaying it.

Comment: to display the image using blob data you need to use a different syntax for the img tag - I'll edit the above to show an example...

Comment: Now you got me I don’t know how to, but I’ll try to explain, in me CPanel when I upload image directly into database the image decodes and I can see it on me web page, but when I upload true php I can’t see it on me web page. And thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: I’m trying really hard to fix this, the code you have given me works, but for some reason I can’t read the picture from me database when I upload using php. In other case when I upload directly true CPanel I can see the picture. Little more help will be great if you can help. Thanks

Comment: one thing to be aware of is spaces in the base64 encoded string ~ I think, from memory, that you need to replace them with `+` but I can't fully remember. I'd suggest that you take a known image, parse it through `file_get_contents` to get the raw file data - base 64 encode it and then try using that data in an `img` tag as shown above. If it doesn't appear try replacing the spaces with `+` ~ it's quite a long time since I did this I can't fully remember

Comment: Thanks for your reply i found the problem in your code, `$image=base64_encode( file_get_contents( $tmp ) );` . I need to delete base64 encode and it worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think that your database isn't the same that your table.. try this and replace '----datatable---'.
And you must convert the image to blob with file_get_contents

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "----datatable---";
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_product (name, image, price)
      VALUES (:name, :image, :price)');
  $statement->execute([
      ':name' => $name,
      ':image' => $image,
      ':price' => $price
  ]);
  }
}

?>
```